# how to set XHR returned from a method to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm Using CoffeeScript with Jquery. I've got a method named `getVideoTitle` that makes an ajax call to the youtube api to fetch the video title and returns the fetched video title. However, it is returning an object, whereas I just want a string returned. I want a string returned because I am using `backbone.js` and want to fire `create` to create the record on the backend.

```
@collection.create videoid: $('#url').val(), name: @getVideoTitle($('#url').val());
```

Please see an example [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3agetVideoTitle%20=%20%28videourl%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20regex%20=%20/v=%28%5Cw%2a%29&/%0A%20%20%20%20match%20=%20regex.exec%28videourl%29%0A%20%20%20%20videourl%20=%20%22http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%22%2bmatch%5B1%5D%2b%22&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc%22%0A%20%20%20%20%24.getJSON%20videourl,%20%28response%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%20=%20response.data.items%5B0%5D.title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20description%20=%20response.data.items%5B0%5D.description%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20%22title%20inside%22%20%2b%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20title%0A%0Areturned%20=%20getVideoTitle%28%22http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Arats1aL_s4&feature=related%22%29%0A%0Aalert%20%28%22Variable%3a%20%22%20%2b%20returned%29%0A%0A%0A)

How can I return a `string` back from this function?

Comment: Have you tried to inspect that object? Maybe, it has string with title among its field?

Comment: yeah, I've done `console.log()` on it. There are numerous functions and somewhere in there the value is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getVideoTitle` is asynchronous, it's probably returning the XHR object that is handling the request, and expecting a callback to call and receive the result.

So, you need to pass a callback to it, and get the result before creating the collection. Something like this:

```
id = $('#url').val()
@getVideoTitle id, (title) ->
  @collection.create videoid: id, name: title
```

Relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+return+value

I'd recommend brushing up on your javascript skills before moving to CoffeeScript, otherwise you're in for a bumpy ride.

Comment: Ricardo is quite right. The function that makes the Ajax call can't return the result of the Ajax call, because it returns as soon as the Ajax call has been sent. I have a forthcoming book on this subject, *[Async JavaScript](http://leanpub.com/asyncjs/)*.